SimpleJpaRepository saveAll throws exception due to duplicate
i have a repository used in the writer of a spring-batch, it's a simpleJpaRepository, and for the sake of performances, i use saveAll() to save a list of entities. during the save, sometimes the repository throws an exception due to duplicate entities (i have a unicity contstraint in my table, the repository tries to insert a new entity with null id, but fails due to an already existing entity with the same unicity columns). the result is a batch failure.
i would like to find an elegant way to tell the repository "if you find a duplicate, ignore the insert, and move to next entity".
i would like to avoid having to iterate over the list and check for each entity if it exists or not.

How about retrieving an Optional<YourEntity> from the repository and check .isPresent() or using .ifPresent() before proceed?

well, like i said, i'm saving a list of entities, and i would like to avoid to iterate over it in order to check if each one exists. (performance wise)

You can try defining a custom repository implementing a saveAll that can try to save the entity, catch the exception. This will still be iterating and is less performant than a bulk write, so you can use the the @SQLInsert annotation on your entity like:
@SQLInsert(sql = "INSERT INTO entity_table (col1, col2, ...) VALUES (?, ?, ...) ON CONFLICT (unique_column) DO UPDATE SET col1= EXCLUDED.col1, col2= EXCLUDED.col2")
